# Is my Postgresql COPY transaction still running?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psql

I have a large (18GB) CSV file I am trying to load into a database through the use of a python script. My approach is broken down like so:

1. Load the file into a temporary table, this is so the file gets loaded without failing due to any duplicate issues or primary keys.
2. Copy the data from the table into a new table with indexes and Conflict handling for potential dupes.

My python code and the SQL command is as follows:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgres://adatabasestring')
event.listen(engine, 'connect', init_search_path)
connection = engine.raw_connection()
cursor = connection.cursor()

file_path = "/path/to/file.csv"

print("COPYING file to temp table")

keyword_adding_sql = """
                    CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_table 
                    (LIKE working_table INCLUDING DEFAULTS)
                    ON COMMIT DROP;
                    
                    COPY tmp_table FROM '{file_path}' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
                    
                    INSERT INTO working_table
                    SELECT *
                    FROM tmp_table
                    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

                    """

cursor.execute(keyword_adding_sql.format(file_path=file_path))
connection.commit()
```

The script was ran from my local machine but the file it was copying and the database itself are on the remote server. I ran the script and left it running and came back to an error code saying the server closed unexpectedly. I was worried the transaction was cancelled or the like but I queried `pg_stat_activity` and the query itself is still listed as active.

Will the query ever be finished or is it hanging on itself? I checked the `working_table` size and it looks like all the data is there as expected.

Comment: Which query is active? Is `tmp_table` still there? What does the Postgres log show?

Comment: Running pg_stat_activity shows the whole query is running. Its the only query as its a private database. tmp_table does not appear when I use \dt+. Looked at the log at `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log` and no obvious errors show. I'm seeing a lot of `postgres@postgres FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off` in the logs but not sure if its relevant.

Comment: Well: you could do a dummy run, using only a fraction of the file.

Comment: I  was not thinking, you would not be able to see the `tmp_table` created in your command while logged into another session in any case. Do you have `log_statement='mod` set in your postgresql.conf. If so you should be able to see the `INSERT` part of your script. Also what do the *.start(and state_change) fields in `pg_stat_activity` show and do they match what you would expect.  Working on theory there maybe a previous incomplete/uncommitted version of your script still there.

Comment: Appreciate your patience, I don't think log_statement is set up correctly in this case, this was done on a fresh new postgresql (and I am pretty new to DB's). The *_start entries in pg_stat_activity show the time i ran the query originally as expected. I actually took another look at the table size and it seems to be increasing in size to somewhere near where I expected. Perhaps my mistake is that I have an index in one of the columns in `working_table` it is writing to and that is slowing down the process?